# IPhone: Resources to learn 'instruments'?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, instruments

I'd like to use instruments to verify is my program doesn't have any memory leaks.

Can you please provide me with some resources or tips that helped you as you were trying to figure this out? Maybe some video screencasts, or something.

This program is pretty complicated and I'm not too familiar with such low level profiling utils so maybe you found a nice easy to understand tutorial as you were going through this?

Comment: actually it turned out to be pretty simple. just go run->run with performance tool->leaks and then when it's running click on the leaks row. now it'll list the part of your code that has a leak. you just click on that and it'll show you the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cocoa Tutorial: Fixing Memory Leaks With Instruments](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/04/02/cocoa-tutorial-fixing-memory-leaks-with-instruments/)

Instruments also brings a quite good documentation

Answer (score 1):

For finding memory leaks using instruments - http://mobileorchard.com/find-iphone-memory-leaks-a-leaks-tool-tutorial/

You may use Clang Static Analyzer - http://mobileorchard.com/bug-finding-with-clang-5-resources-to-get-you-started/

Thanks,
Sagar.